# No feedback from manager regarding a request for a pay review

Tags: salary, manager

I've been at my current company for 5 years now.

About 4-5 weeks ago, I had a meeting with my manager and I discussed that I would like a pay review due to multiple factors which I explained to my manager.
They verbally agreed that I should be given a pay rise, but they said they would need to speak to their manager (my director) to discuss how it works within the business.

Over the first week, my manager had to put together a document with similar job roles with salaries, this document did highlight that similar roles had a higher salary than myself. My manager then sent this to my director by the end of the 2nd week.

I have asked my manager a couple of times since then whether there has been any progress/feedback regarding the pay review, every time I ask, I just get told that my director should be booking a meeting in with me to discuss "within the next few days" but I never hear anything from my director.
I don't have anything in writing stating this, but I do have multiple meetings in my calendar with my manager where a pay review was discussed.

Should I speak with my director to understand what the current situation is or should I just wait it out and assume that if I don't hear anything that the pay review isn't going to happen?

Another point to consider, my manager has a habit of saying they have done things, but not actually doing them. It is entirely possible that this document has not been sent to my director, so my director may not be aware of my original request to my manager.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How should I properly approach my boss if I'm feeling underpaid?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/1025/how-should-i-properly-approach-my-boss-if-im-feeling-underpaid)

Comment: Are there other positions available locally which offer you what you want? If yes, then it may be time to take advantage of that...

Comment: How long has it been since they raised your salary? How long has the manager worked for the company? How big is the company? I ask these questions because it seems like you and your manager have never had to address this issue before.

Answer (score 1):

As you say you have been at this company for 5 years, you should be aware of how the manager works and how the director works.

If you know that the manager has a tendency to let things lie on his desk then you have the choice to submit it to his director - however be aware of the fallout ie it not producing the results you want.

Is the director known for "ostrich" management - ie waiting for the issue to die a graceful death? You have the choice to ask for a meeting with the director. But again, will the fallout be what you want.

Or do you find out about other opportunities and play the "I might leave" game. As you know the management and the current position of the company then you can evaluate the consequences of your decisions.

Good luck in what you choose.